# Error 500 on localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I recently installed `apache2` and `phpmyadmin` on localhost, and everytime I try to connect to `localhost/phpmyadmin` I get prompted with an "Enter your username/password". I enter root as the username and my own password. When I do this, I get brought to a page that says this:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Here is my apache2 error log:

```
[Sun Nov 02 20:54:42.675681 2014] [authn_file:error] [pid 10548] (2)No such file or directory: [client 127.0.0.1:33730] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/apache2/.phpmyadmin.htpasswd
[Sun Nov 02 20:58:16.862329 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10542] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Nov 02 20:58:17.952658 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10889] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 02 20:58:17.952714 2014] [core:notice] [pid 10889] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Nov 02 20:58:22.247743 2014] [authn_file:error] [pid 10893] (2)No such file or directory: [client 127.0.0.1:33761] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/apache2/phpmyadmin.htpasswd
[Sun Nov 02 20:58:23.369528 2014] [authn_file:error] [pid 10894] (2)No such file or directory: [client 127.0.0.1:33762] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/apache2/phpmyadmin.htpasswd
[Sun Nov 02 20:58:23.791622 2014] [authn_file:error] [pid 10895] (2)No such file or directory: [client 127.0.0.1:33763] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/apache2/phpmyadmin.htpasswd
[Sun Nov 02 21:01:53.884507 2014] [authn_file:error] [pid 10893] (2)No such file or directory: [client 127.0.0.1:33951] AH01620: Could not open password file: /etc/apache2/phpmyadmin.htpasswd`
```

Any idea how to fix this? I did try searching askubuntu for an answer and tried several methods, but none of them seemed to work.